# Flutter Firebase DebugView not sending events

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

Initially the person before me set up a screen observer so that whenever the page changes, setCurrentScreen is triggered to send a event and log the screen. Because we use a bunch of open containers to animate page opening, the screen observer doesnt get triggered. So I went through the app and added some setCurrentScreen for those that the screenObserver missed, and while there I also added some logEvents to see if people are using specific parts of the app.

The way I set enabled debug view was in xcode, going to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and adding -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled and -FIRDebugEnabled [Edit scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZJkS.png)

After ticking both of the above (or just one or the other), only these events are being triggered then the app stops sending events. Completely. What am I missing? [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a1uH.png)

I cannot find another issue about this. I am using the same package name in the app and firebase, otherwise I would have no output. All other issues are talking about no output at all. I have tried to do this on simulator and on actual iPhone and they both yield the same result. I have also set up a android emulator and have an actual phone. Tried it on both and same result. The above screenshot is from iPhone as I am on Mac and more comfortable working on a iPhone.

i have set IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED to true in the .plist file and this did not work

Comment: If you create a button to trigger Analytics events, can you see those events in debug view? In Xcode output, do you see any Analytics events being triggered? It would be interesting to see if the events stopped working after changing the page or some other action.

Comment: Hello Frank and thanks for taking time out of your day to leave a comment.

I made a FAB and attached a print and a Analytics logEvent to the onPressed. Unfortunately pressing the button triggers the print but no logEvent is seen on debugView. There is nothing from Analytics in the xcode console.

Comment: I am also very sure that this will work once the app is out in production as we do have screenView and logEvents being shown in Firebase console. Just wanted to see if my events made sense T_T